# Bayesian structural time series with few data points (using CausalImpact)

Tags: time-series, bayesian, state-space-models, causalimpact

I am experimenting with the `CausalImpact` package https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html (Brodersen et al. 2015) which uses Bayesian structural time-series models.

All of their examples have many time points pre and post intervention.

In my data set, I only have **4** measurements before the intervention, and **20** after the intervention.

Is this a problem for the validity of the model? 
I could not find something about how many time points you should have, but for example, the very similar `prophet` package says you should have many.
I can provide several covariates, perhaps that helps.